# XRPL: Check last 3 transactions only

Tags: https, xrp

Im looking for a way to check the last 3 transactions to a specific XRP wallet

Im using this link: https://data.ripple.com/v2/accounts/rBn1tX24h6H7SZT8mRe9oUypVJNNGgcav8/transactions

But it shows me all the transactions. I would like to see the 3 most recent ones only.
And i cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the limit parameter:

```
https://data.ripple.com/v2/accounts/rBn1tX24h6H7SZT8mRe9oUypVJNNGgcav8/transactions?limit=3
```

But I would suggest to go with "public rippled method/command" **[account_tx](https://xrpl.org/account_tx.html)**,  where you can also specify the limit.

If you don't want to use websocket and just want to use REST API then you can follow this tutorial: [Interacting with XRP Ledger using JSON-RPC](https://learn.xumm.dev/xrpl/interacting-with-xrp-ledger-using-json-rpc)